# Why cannot transfer variable value?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script as follow:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2 skip=3 delims= " %%a in (Instance_list.txt) do (
Set Intance_NAME=%%a
echo %Intance_NAME%
```

But The echo part is empty(Nothing).
Could you please tell me why and help me with this?

Comment: You have delayed expansion enabled but you are not referencing the variable correctly.  You need to use exclamation points instead of percent symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

You activate `delayedexpansion` but never use it (see the replacement of `%` in the last line with `!`

You also do not need to use `"delims= " on whitespace as whitespace are default delimiters in batch.

You did not close the loop with a closing `(`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2 skip=3" %%a in (Instance_list.txt) do (
Set Intance_NAME=%%a
echo !Intance_NAME!
)
```

and lastly, you do not really need `delayedexpansion` if you do not set the variable inside the loop, so you could also do:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2 skip=3" %%a in (Instance_list.txt) do echo %%a
```